# Templating in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Simple question here, but I found no useful resource. Is templating possible in Electron? Using Jade or Handlebars to display dynamic templates? I know there is .loadURL() that takes a static html file.

Is dynamic possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could give electron-pug a chance. https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-pug

Answer (score 4):

You can register a new buffer protocol via [protocol.registerBufferProtocol](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/protocol/#protocolregisterbufferprotocolscheme-handler-completion).

`main.js`

```
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var protocol = electron.protocol;
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var pug = require('pug');

var window;

app.on('ready', function () {

  // Define the `pug` scheme
  protocol.registerBufferProtocol('pug', function (request, callback) {
    var url = path.normalize(request.url.substr(7));
    var content = pug.renderFile(url);
    callback({
      mimeType: 'text/html',
      data: new Buffer(content)
    });
  });

  window = new BrowserWindow({width: 600, height: 600});

  // Load your file using the `pug` protocol
  window.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.pug'),
    protocol: 'pug:',
    slashes: true
  }));

});
```

`index.pug`

```
html
  head
    title My title
  body
    h1 Hello world!
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Could you tell me how to pass some data to template using this method?

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly be possible to use Jade or Handlebars for dynamic templating by running a local server in the Electron main process. I would not recommend this however, as it is kind of backwards. Electron is primarily a front end framework and while running a local server is good for some things, templating is not really one of them.

Most people use a frontend JS framework like Angular or React.

Comment: Handlebars is perfectly suitable in a frontend environment.

Comment: This is true.... not to mention that eg. Angular has a own template feature and is designed for the MVC pattern so it doesn't need an extra overlay like another template engine.
For Node.js yes, but for Electron no.

Comment: For a single page application, like the app writen in electron (where content should be loaded dynamically), it might actually be an overkill to use one of these huge JS frontend frameworks. Instead, using a simple templating library like `pug` or `handlebars` along with plain JS or even TypeScript is the way to go in my opinion. I don't understand why people think that when using Electron, there is a requirement for a bloated frontend framework, when in fact a simple templating library (if you use single-page app where content changes dynamically) and the plain JS is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to add here but thought it might be worthwhile. I have added a package to deal with adding views from any renderer and handle asset paths. So far I have just added the ejs renderer but plan on adding pug and haml as additional default renderers, but it is easy to extend and add your own as well. The package is called electron-view-renderer https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-view-renderer

Hopefully this can help someone like it did our team. It is in its infancy, so all comments and contributions welcome

Answer (score 0):

U can use ejs-electron to achieve the same purpose. U can check it out on github & simply install it as follows:
npm i ejs-electron --save
Just require it in ur main js file