# Unable to read API key from rendered process which is defined in preload.js for inter-process communication in electronJS

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm getting an undefined object error for the api key (setScripts) in rendered process (i.e. install.js). I'm trying to capture data in rendered process and send it to main process (i.e. main.js) with the help of preload.js.

**the error->**  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setScripts')
at HTMLButtonElement. (install.js:10:38)

-> **install.js**

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#BtnInstall');

    btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="installOption"]:checked');
        const values = [];
        checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
            values.push(checkbox.value);
        });
        window.installScriptsAPI.setScripts(values);
        for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox1')) {
            checkbox.checked = false //for unselection
        }
    });
```

->**preload.js**

```
const{ contextBridge, ipcRendrer} = require('electron');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('installScriptsAPI',{
setScripts: (values) => ipcRendrer.send('install-scripts',values)
})
```

->**main.js**

```
 console.log('main process working');
 const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
 const path = require('path')

 function createWindow(){
 const win = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences :{
 nodeIntegration:true,
 contextIsolation:false,
 preload: path.join(__dirname,'preload.js')
 }, width: 1000, height: 600 })
 win.loadFile('index.html');

 win.webContents.openDevTools();
 }

 function catchInstallScripts(event,values){
 console.log(values);
 }


 app.whenReady().then(() => {
 createWindow(); 
 ipcMain.on('install-scripts',catchInstallScripts);
 });
 app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu-sandbox');
```

Comment: Typo: `ipcRendrer` -> `ipcRenderer` (this doesn't cause the error though afaik)

Comment: The error is telling you that `window.installScriptsAPI` is undefined. Can you try to console.log() it in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I did console.log(window.installScriptsAPI); and it's showing "undefined". Also corrected the typo but the error is still there.

Comment: Hmm. I added `console.log("preload.js");` to preload.js and I can see it as the very first console entry inside the dev tools. Can you try that?

Comment: yeah, I tried it's the first console entry inside dev tools. You want me to make some changes in that?

Comment: No, just wanted to make sure it runs. I'm stumped by this tbh.

Comment: I created a test project using your code. Guess what happens when I check the console? `Error: contextBridge API can only be used when contextIsolation is enabled`. Guess what happens when I change to `contextIsolation: true`? It works on the spot.

Comment: In main.js, I changed the contextIsolation from false to true (in the above code) still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: You should get an error in your console about that. Did you check the console for errors? I mean you are calling `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('installScriptsAPI', ...)` so that either works or causes an error message. Can you put your repo on github or something?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that error in console, sure I'll create a repo on github and send the link here

Comment: Couldn't upload on git, this is the drive link containing the folder, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1S7_S7H3Fj6y5BV2B4QtGXD1aC8ULxtrd?usp=sharing

Comment: Please delete the node_modules folder, that's hundreds of megabytes not necessary to upload

Comment: I found the cause: you are loading the page HTML inside an <iframe> and it looks like you cannot use exposed stuff in there.

Comment: thanks, any suggestions to what I should use instead of iframe, I'm fairly new to web dev just started, and thanks for the help I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Well, I guess you're using the iframe so you don't have to copy the navigation to each page, correct? You could put the navigation into an iframe instead I guess. In my last electron app I used React and React Router for this but maybe that's overkill. There are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573159/templating-in-electron